# Degree of splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Given an irreducible polynomial $f\in F[x]$ of degree $n$ and letting $E$ be its splitting field, is it true that every root $\alpha$ of $f$ has degree $n$ so $F(\alpha)=E$? Furthermore $[E:F]=n-s$ where $s$ is the number of repeated roots of $f$?

I've read that $[E:F]$ can be up to $n!$ but don't understand how that can be possible.

Comment: Yes, every root $\alpha$ of $f$ has degree $n$ in that $[F(\alpha) : F] = n$, but that doesn't imply that $F(\alpha) = E$.  Consider $f = x^3 - 2$ over $F = \mathbb{Q}$, for example: $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity, so $[E : F] = 6$, but $[F(\sqrt[3]{2}) : F] = 3$.

Comment: Is there some concept of "linearly independent" extensions/roots that you can "factor" extensions into? Or is $Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ not a splitting field?

Comment: Indeed, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not a splitting field.  The other two roots of $x^3 - 2$ are $\omega \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2}$, and these are not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. (If we take $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to be the real cube root, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ but the other two roots are complex.)  You can factor the extension into simple extensions: $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})(\omega)$.

Comment: Or maybe you mean [linearly disjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_disjoint) extensions.  The subfields $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ are linearly disjoint and their compositum is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega)$.

Comment: I see, so some roots are inherently "inseparable" from each other via polynomial splitting. Does this have anything to do with inseparable extensions in non-zero characteristic?

Comment: No, I don't think this has anything to do with inseparable extensions.  We adjoin one root $\alpha$ of $x^3 - 2$, and then ask what the minimal polynomial is for the other roots over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.  This turns out to be $x^2 + \alpha x + \alpha^2$ (which looks suspiciously similar to the third cyclotomic polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$).